# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1{x} \cos^{-1} (\frac{\sin x}{x})$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Today I came across the following limit problem:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1{x} \cos^{-1} \Big(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big)$$

---

**Here's my work:**

$$\begin{align}L &= \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1{x} \cos^{-1}\left (\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) \tag{1}
\\& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin h}{h}\right)\tag{2}
\\& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)
\\ & =  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)}\cdot \left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)
\\& =  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)}\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)\tag{3}
\\& =  \lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2 h}{h^2}}\right)
\\& = \lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt\frac{h + \sin h}{h} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{h -\sin h}{h^3}}
\\& = \lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sin h}{h} } \cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt{\frac{h -\sin h}{h^3}}\tag{4}
\\& = \sqrt{2} \cdot \frac1{\sqrt{6}}\\& = \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\end{align}$$

**Details:**

> $(1)$ Putting $x = 0 + h$ as $x \to 0^+$, $h\to 0$.
>
> $(2)$ Used $\cos^{-1}(x) = \sin^{-1}\sqrt{1-x^2}$.
>
> $(3)$ Used $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1} x}{x} = 1$.
>
> $(4)$ Used $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}= 1$ for the first limit. And the second limit is evaluated using Maclaurin Series of $\sin h$.

---

Although I'm able to solve it but my method is too long. I'm looking for a shorter or alternative way to do it.

Comment: Is use of l'Hôpital's rule out of the question?

Comment: @user170231 Oh yes. I forgot to mention Lhospital rule is not allowed.

Comment: Probably then you're also not allowed to use Maclaurin series?

Comment: @GregMartin I didn't get any other way to evaluate the limit so I used that.

Comment: Not sure if I would call this long. Given the arccos, I'm surprised that you could even do it without l'hopital. That way you got rid of the arccos was pretty clever

Comment: It's [possible to show through purely geometrical means](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~CLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/subsection-25.html) that
$\cos h \le \frac{\sin h}h \le 1$, but that turns out to be far from strong enough to evaluate this limit.

Comment: Simply replacing $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ by its limit (i.e. $1$) leads to the wrong answer. This shows that one *has* to use the next term in the Taylor expansion $\sin x \approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + O(x^5)$ to work out exactly how much $\cos^{-1}(\frac{\sin x}{x})$ differs from $0$. That is, one cannot avoid such a computation (and using the idea I described, one "rigorously" shows that such an issue cannot be overlooked). Basically, you cannot do this question without the knowledge that $\frac{\sin x - x}{x^3} \to \frac{-1}{6}$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: In my opinion your proof is short and clever (+).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is correct and the working can be simplified a lot by writing $(\sin x) /x=\cos t$ so that $t\to 0^+$.

Then we have $$\frac{t} {x} =\sqrt{\frac{t^2}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{t^2}{1-\cos t} \cdot\frac{1-\cos t} {x^2}}$$ The first factor inside the square root tends to $2$ and hence desired limit equals the limit of $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{x-\sin x} {x^3}}$$ Thus the desired limit is $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1/6}=1/\sqrt{3}$.

The square roots are introduced in the working because the most familiar limit associated with $\cos $ function is $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1-\cos t} {t^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 4):

First note that $\left|\frac{\sin x}x\right|\le1,$ which allows to define $t:=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right).$

As $x\to0,$ we have $t\to0^+,$ $\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\to-\frac16$ and $\frac{\cos t-1}{t^2}\to-\frac12,$ hence (using the notion of [asymptotic equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition)):
$$-\frac{x^2}6\sim\frac{\sin x}x-1=\cos t-1\sim-\frac{t^2}2.$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac tx=\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt{\frac {t^2}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac26}=\frac1{\sqrt3}.$$

Comment: Perhaps you meant define $y:=\cos^{-1} \left( {\sin x \over x}\right)$?

Comment: Very clever! (+)